# Is there a better word than 'individualization' to describe a class-based or communitarian society moving to an individualized society?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Trying to summarize the process of a class-based or communitarian society moving to an individualized society, in particular to highlight the negative aspects. The word "individualization" is a bit ambiguous. Is there a better word for this? (preferably less than 8 syllables)

This is being used as a subhead, so I can't provide a sample sentence.

Comment: *More individualized*? *Make it personal*? *Are Individuals more Self-Absorbed?*

Comment: This is tricky. 'Independence' is often a good trait, while 'isolationism' usually refers to national policies.

Comment: I doubt there is a dedicated word for this highly specific aspect of "social change" going on in various cultures / countries around the world today. If it keeps happening, the world's (predominantly Anglophone) social scientists might invent or co-opt a dedicated term, but for the time being I'd say it's just a sub-component of [***Westernization.***](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Westernization) - that can be adequately described n *many* words, so there's no overriding need for a *single* word that might not always be understood *precisely*, if at all.

Comment: ... Everyone knows that Western society pays far more attention to the importance of the ***individual***, where other cultures often attach greater importance to ***collective society*** (and/or sometimes the "mystical" advantages of reducing one's sense of personal identity to a minimum, in pursuit of "enlightenment", or whatever).

Comment: ...and it's only a comment, so I hope I won;t get too much blowback for this "Copy&Paste" from chatgpt: *The process by which a culture evolves towards giving more importance to the individual and placing emphasis on personal identity and autonomy is often referred to as "**individualization**" or "**individualism**." Social scientists use these terms to describe the shift from traditional collective or communal values to a focus on individual rights, freedom, and self-expression.*

Comment: *Class-based* does not stand in contrast to *individualized*. Although the question is worded as a single word request, it calls for too much **substantive** theoretical discussion to be properly addressed at a site devoted to English language as such. The question should have been closed before any answers appeared, but it is too late to do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Atomized](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atomize)* has just three syllables, and carries this meaning in social sciences. With just one additional syllable, *[atomistic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atomistic)* is also a candidate.

> In an atomized society, others become phantoms all too easily, grist for the mill of resentment and mistrust. [(Anand Pandia in *The Guardian,* 16 Jan 2022)](https://www.theguardian.com/global/2022/jan/16/look-around-you-why-increasingly-polarized)

> The Chippewa social order has often been called "atomistic." The term refers to a loose form of social organization in which corporate organization and political authority are weak. (Victor Barnouw, *Wisconsin Chippewa Myths and Tales and Their Relation to Chippewa Life* [Madison: U of Wisconsin P, 1977], p. 7)

If you feel you really must use an abstract noun for the process, note that a gerund can often serve that function, and *atomizing* has fewer syllables than *atomization.*

Comment: Many good answers, this fits my purposes best. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **insularity** carries both the required sense and the connotation of disapproval.

> *Insular*:
>
> If you say that someone is insular, you are being critical of them
> because they are unwilling to meet new people or to consider new
> ideas. [disapproval].

and

> *insular*
>
> ...
>
> 2. remote, detached, or aloof

[Collins Dictionary {1}](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/insular#:%7E:text=insular%20ADJECTIVE%20%2F%CB%88%C9%AAnsj%CA%8Al%C9%99%2F-,If%20you%20say%20that%20someone%20is%20insular%2C%20you%20are%20being,They%20were%20an)]
and [[Collins Dictionary {2}](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/insular)]

> *insular*  [adjective]:
>
> ...
>
> 2.
>
> a. Suggestive of the isolated life of an island:
>
> - *He is an exceedingly insular man, so deeply private as to seem inaccessible to the scrutiny of a novelist* (Leonard Michaels).
>
> b. Circumscribed and detached in outlook and experience; narrow or
> provincial.

[[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/insularity)]

As mentioned above, 'independence' is often a good trait in a person, while 'isolationism' usually refers to national policies.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***DIFFERENTIATION*** *(differentiated, differentiate)* as borrowed from the lexicon of psychologist [Murray Bowen.](https://www.thebowencenter.org/differentiation-of-self)

In a Bowenian lens,

> A person with a well-differentiated “self” recognizes his realistic dependence on others, but he can stay calm and clear headed enough in the face of conflict, criticism, and rejection to distinguish thinking rooted in a careful assessment of the facts from thinking clouded by emotionality. Thoughtfully acquired principles help guide decision-making about important family and social issues, making her less at the mercy of the feelings of the moment. What she decides and what she says match what she does. He can act selflessly, but his acting in the best interests of the group is a thoughtful choice, not a response to relationship pressures. Confident in his thinking, he can support others’ views without being a disciple or reject others’ views without polarizing the differences.

By contrast, a poorly-differentiated individual tends to

> ...depend so heavily on the acceptance and approval of others that they either quickly adjust what they think, say, and do to please others or they dogmatically proclaim what others should be like and pressure them to conform.

(See The Bowen Center for the Study of the Family:  https://www.thebowencenter.org)

The sociological implications of Bowen's description are reflected in David Riesman's seminal work of the 1950's *The Lonely Crowd*.  Riesman's notions of "inner direction" and "other direction" would seem to mirror the sort of sociological progression posited by the question. Borrowing Bowen's terminology may be rhetorically neater.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be referring to the breakdown of the class structures and the end of smaller communities.   You can call that **disintegration**  or **social disintegration** if you wish to emphasize the negative aspects of those processes.

Compare: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3820086/